# Prestashop + custom theme how to put the Cart in the Nav bar

Tags: prestashop

In prestashop I want to have my cart block in displaynav position. I hooked it from header to displaynav hook, but it does not display correctly, css has to be modified. Can somebodey help me, what i need to change in what css.. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I did something that works but is quite dirty. Hopefully, someone will post a better answer. Also, I assume you're on the downloaded version of PS and not the cloud one. To my knowledge you can't customize like that with the saas solution :s

So I went to the css of my blockcart module ( themes\default-bootstrap\css\modules\blockcart\blockcart.css ) and adapted the first few lines to this

`#header .shopping_cart {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:860px;
  padding-top: 0px; }`

I also commented out the little arrow for convenience ( in "#header .shopping_cart > a:first-child:after" comment the line with "content" ). Try using F12 and make live edits, it's quite useful with PrestaShop ! You get to know to which files are the elements related to.

Anyway, hope it helped and that someone will propose a cleaner way to do this ^^

Comment: Just a little update : It's way better if you put the cart on the left of the nav, it prevents your cart to mask the name of the client or the logout button. You can try to put it at the right of the login button otherwise... ( didn't do it yet ). But it confirms that my method is not optimized at all ^^'